# Hadoop file system from non-hadoop machine

Tags: linux, filesystems, hadoop

I'm having a difficult time finding information on this issue because so many of the results in my searches turn up basic information about copying files from a machine that's part of a cluster.

Problem:  I have a hadoop 3 node cluster that's running hdfs.  Everything is working fine.  I can use files view, I can copy files to it from Windows, I can copy files from the local filesystem to hdfs, I can view directories, create, delete, etc.

I have another machine that's not a part of the cluster.  It's running Dremio (fwiw), and it's also the machine that processes the files that I eventually need to copy to the hdfs file system.  Dremio is working fine, but I'm trying access the hdfs file system from this machine and I'm not entirely sure how I should be doing that correctly.

Since I'm running scripts that used to run (correctly) on a machine that was part of the cluster, I installed just the hadoop-client (to get access to hdfs -dfs) and I updated the lines to reference the hdfs cluster (rather than assuming it was local).  That command looks like this:

```
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal test.txt hdfs://ws-hdfs01:50070/Data/
```

This exact command works just fine from the `ws-hdfs01` box (removing the `hdfs://ws-hdfs01:70050/`), but on the machine that's not part of the cluster I get the following error:

```
19/06/04 12:11:09 WARN net.NetUtils: Unable to wrap exception of type class org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcException: it has no (String) constructor
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcException.<init>(java.lang.String)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:830)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:806)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1501)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1443)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1353)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:228)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:116)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:900)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:1660)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$29.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1583)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$29.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1580)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1595)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.getFileStatus(Globber.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.doGlob(Globber.java:281)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.glob(Globber.java:149)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:2016)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.PathData.expandAsGlob(PathData.java:353)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination.getRemoteDestination(CommandWithDestination.java:195)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CopyCommands$CopyFromLocal.processOptions(CopyCommands.java:348)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.run(Command.java:176)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.run(FsShell.java:328)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:90)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.main(FsShell.java:391)
copyFromLocal: Failed on local exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcException: RPC response exceeds maximum data length; Host Details : local host is: "ws-bi01[fqdn removed]/10.0.10.37"; destination host is: "ws-hdfs01":50070;
```

If there's a better command to copy files to the system, I would much rather just uninstall the hadoop client and do it that way, but like I said, I'm having a hard time trying to find it because of the thousands of search results about how to copy files from the local system to the hdfs file system from a machine that's part of the cluster.

Comment: Does your `hdfs-site.xml` contain [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50484373/165358)?

Comment: Correct, that doesn't make any difference and still gives me the same error.